# How to call LWC from custom quick action or button from List View of objects?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, list-view, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

Well I have created quick action and button, Button has no option to call LWC and quick If I create quick action by referencing LWC in it, then its not displaying in list view.

If it is feasible, if so then what I am missing ?

Comment: Can anyone have any idea or any doc that shows that it is not feasible or its a limit.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232

Answer (score 1):

LWC Quickactions are unfortunately currently not yet supported in Listviews. Only on record details.

Comment: can you provide me any idea or discussion from success community.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232